# When start geth(Ethereum client) First time,showing message like "generating DAG for epoch ........." mining is taking too much to start

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets, dag

**What i have**
**Case 1.** following command line without `--dev` option (take too much time to start to mining)

```
geth --datadir ~/privateBlockChain1 --mine --minerthreads 1 --networkid 1300 --rpcport 8000  --port 30301 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin" --rpc --maxpeers 0 --nodiscover --targetgaslimit 110000000000 console
```

**Case 2.** following command line with `--dev` option(using this command line argument , mining works fine)

```
geth --datadir ~/privateBlockChain1 --mine --minerthreads 1 --networkid 1300 --rpcport 8000  --port 30301 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin" --rpc --maxpeers 0 --nodiscover --targetgaslimit 110000000000 **--dev** console
```

**Scenario**

1. Start geth by case 1 command.   Step 2.
2. suppose block created by case 1 command as for example -> #34544 block
3. Start geth by case 2 command
4. Block start creating from #1
   block , it is not resume from #34544 block, how to fix it.

**What i want?**

a) how to mining start quickly(with in a second or a minute) when i start geth command line
b) if i do'nt want to use --dev option , then how can start mining fast?
c) suppose if you say, --dev is only option to start mining fast in startup, then how can i resume mine block from previous(i.e #34544 not from #1 block)
d) what is the advantage and disadvantage of --dev option with geth.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/dd06c8584368316c8fb388384b0723d8c7e543f0/cmd/utils/flags.go#L775) the `--dev` option appears to only turn off networking.  No listening, no discovery of other nodes.  So I don't immediately assume you can't use the `--networkid` option as well.

I am seeing a lot of talk about how the `--dev` flag prevents you from being a part of a test network(including the private network you setup). However, I have not been able to corroborate this within the source code within my 15 minutes of research.  If I find out definitively, I'll update my answer.

Assuming that's true, the `--dev` flag will always create a standalone network and always start at block #1.  So I guess my advice is to not use `--dev` if you don't want to start from scratch every time.